# Multiplication with Dynamic Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Currently working on a school project with dynamic integers, the goal is for someone to be able to input 2 integers of any number of digits and then output those two numbers added, subtracted and multiplied. I've gotten the subtraction and addition to work (for the most part) but the multiplication completely eludes me.

I've attempted to use the pow function but doesn't work with int variables, currently it will only multiply the digits in the same subscript on the opposite array. (I.E. array1[0] * array2[0], array1[1] * array2[1] etc.)

this obviously wont give the correct answer as it makes 100 x 2 = 100.

the code specifically for the multiplication portion is:

```
//preforming multiplication tasks
for (int i = arraySize; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (numList1[i].value() == 0 || numList2[i].value() == 0)
  {
    numResults[i].setValue(numResults[i].add(numList1[i].add(numList2[i].value())));
  }
  else
  {
  numResults[i].setValue(numResults[i].add(numList1[i].multiply(numList2[i].value())));
  }

  while (numResults[i].value() > 9)
  {
    numResults[i].setValue(numResults[i].subtract(10));
    numResults[i-1].setValue(numResults[i-1].add(1));
  }
}
```

The function calls are as follows:

```
    int largeIntegers::add(const int otherInt)
  {
    int result;
    result = num + otherInt;
    return result;
  }

  int largeIntegers::multiply(const int otherInt)
  {
    int result;
    if (num != 0){
    result = num * otherInt;
    }
    else {
      result = num + otherInt;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

The other obvious problem is when the results become larger than the array can hold (the array is initiated at the size of the largest entered variable, so 100 * 20 would appear as 000, because the array wouldnt have a place to put the 2.

Help with either of these 2 problems would be much appreciated.

Comment: A simple approach is to store your values in reverse order (_i.e._ little-endian). That makes it trivial to enlarge a number because you can just append new values onto the end. As for your question about `pow`, what exactly do you need that for? If you're doing long multiplication in base 10, the only possible application of this is effectively a shift. You barely need anything special for that. In fact, you can keep your number as it is and simply pass the "exponent" into your addition function which will start at the _nth_ position.

Comment: N digit number * M digit number result could be potentially How many digits? As you've already realized, you need to allow for that - provide a bigger output array. You can calculate the max number of digits from the number of digits in the multiplicands. (Also note that addition may also needs a larger output buffer, but not as much larger.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. What are `numList` and `numResults`? Are they plain arrays, `std::array`s or `std::vector`s? Of what?

Comment: @Bob__ I believe they are pointer variables to std::arrays of a custom class largeIntegers, each subscript of the arrays hold a single int digit.

Comment: I hadn't particularly noted, but your posted "largeIntegers::add" and "largeIntegers::multiply" don't seem to be at all real not only regarding their contents, but also their signature. The correct function signature to match your problem description would be taking a parameter of type largeIntegers, not int.

Comment: @paddy the idea with the Pow was to multiply the stored int by 10 ^ abs(i-arraysize), thus making the code read the numbers as they would be in reality such as 20 being read as 20 rather than 2 and 0

Comment: @AviBerger yes I realized that, I just do not know how to correct it. I could initiate the array at some unfathomably long number but that would be a waste of resources and im sure would get me marks off from my professor.

Comment: 'int largeIntegers::multiply(const int otherInt)' would be a single constant int argument - not a pointer, not a custom class, and not capable of accommodating am "integer of any number of digits". It should probably be something like `largeInteger largeInteger::multiply(const largeInteger otherInt)`. (I've made the class name singular, as I presume it is to maintanine one largeIntegerValue.) Presumably it contains something like a std::vector<unsigned char> to hold the digits and your multiply function would use additional such vectors as local variables for intermediate calculations.

Comment: To set a value, you might pass in a std::string containing only digits. The length on the string gives you the length for the vector. Adding 2 positive numbers, the result would have either max digits or max digits + 1 of the inputs.

Comment: For multiply, you can calculate the number of result digits within 1 just from the number of digits of the multiplicands.

Comment: You don't want to "making the code read the numbers as they would be in reality such as 20 being read as 20 rather than 2 and 0" internally as that would not be able to accommodate the size of numbers you are dealing with. Do you have your class definition and a genuinely working add function? Get that much working first.

Comment: Do you remember & understand how long multiplication works? If not, google it & spend some time reviewing it.

Answer (score 0):

If your addition functions works, then you can use that for multiplication.

Example:

```
5 * 11 -->  11 + 11 + 11 + 11 + 11
```

So, it is the just doing additions in a loop.

Untested Pseudo code would be:

```
int largeIntegers::multiply(const int otherInt) {
    int result;

    if (num == 0 or otherInt == 0){
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
      result = num;
      for (int i=0; i < otherInt - 1; ++i)
          result = add(otherInt);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

The above is most likely wrong and just given for a demo for the algorithm.

I do not know your code. Therefore you need to understand the base algorithm and then implement that mechanism

Comment: This might be unfeasible (as in, the life time of universe is not enough to complete the calculation), if the goal is to calculate for example `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000 * 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000`...

Comment: @Armin Montigny
except since the input numbers are split into arrays of digits 5x11 would be treated as 1x5 and 1x0 (05x11) this is where my problem lies.